# What happened to iTunes File Sharing in macOS Catalina?

Tags: itunes, catalina

What happened to iTunes File Sharing in macOS Catalina?

Is file sharing to iPhone completely gone?

Comment: Did you try accessing it in Finder?

Comment: i'm not sure how you would access in finder? it's usually sandboxed based on each ios app that supports it... does ifinder now list the apps on an iphone?

Comment: When I wrote that I was referring to this: https://youtu.be/psL_5RIBqnY?t=6371 , but carefully going through the video again, it makes me wonder if Apple zapped iTunes File Sharing feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s in Files as of today. Just tested exporting a zip file from lumafusion for iTunes file sharing and when I go to Finder on my Mac, click on iPad, then files option, then lumafusion app...I can see the zip file. But I was only able to delete it. I could not copy it to my machine, might be a bug in the current beta. I have iPadOS and Mac OS Catalina most up to date public betas on these devices as of today.

EDIT: If you want to copy files from your iPhone to your mac, simply drag the files to a folder in your mac.

Photo below of this process on my Mac:
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "Finder for my iPad"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added a photo. Meant Finder on my Mac then click on iPad (HackerPad name for me)

Comment: This is a pretty useful feature that I use quite often; do you know if there's any way to access this "Files" section from the command line?

Comment: NICE! so it is . finally no longer a random feature in iTunes

Comment: I much preferred the random feature in iTunes, it was a much better user experience. I had access to a context menu (right-click) to copy / paste and the iTunes status would tell you the progress. Now there is only drag & drop (both ways), it's not clear when the process has started and there is no way to know the progress... For large files, it's nerve-racking. I really hope they improve this extremely common and essential feature. Copy & paste, d'oh! P.s. @Shervin, IMHO your answer could use some clarification for inexperienced users. Thanks anyway!